# How to check if MongoDB is up and running using reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to write a helper function that will allow my dashboard to check if MongoDB is running on not. Based on the result, it could warn admins on the visual dashboard. I read through the reactive mongo docs [here](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.MongoConnection) and I have the following function so far but unfortunately its not working.

```
import reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver

def isMongoUp(host: String): Boolean = {

  var connected = false
  val driver = new MongoDriver()
  val connection = driver.connection(List(host))
  val db = connection("myDB")
  db.map {
    case Failure(e) => connected = false
    case Success(result) => connected = true
  }

}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
def isMongoUp(host: String): Boolean = {
  var connected = false
  val driver = new MongoDriver()
  val connection = driver.connection(List(host))
  val db = connection.database("myDB")
  db.map {
    case sth:DefaultDB => connected = true
    case _ => connected = false
  }
  connected

}

val result = isMongoUp("localhost")
result
```

Comment: Use `connection.database(..)` instead of `connection(..)`, this will wait until the DB is resolved (according the failover strategy).

Comment: @cchantep: I made those changes however my `result` always returns false. Please see my UPDATE 1

Comment: You cannot match on `.database` result, it's a future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it done this way:

```
def isMongoUp(host: String): Boolean = {

    val driver = new MongoDriver()
    val connection = driver.connection(List(host))
    val db = connection.database("myDB")
    val connectedFuture: Future[Boolean] = db.map { list =>
      list match {
        case sth: DefaultDB => true
        case _ => false
      }
    }.recover { case error: Throwable => false}
    val timeout = scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds")

    val result = Await.result(connectedFuture, timeout)
    result

  }
```

Comment: The pat-mat insise the future is useless.